# Probability of getting at least two 6 with 12 dice

Tags: probability

I have 12 dice. I want to know how likely it is to get two 6's. MY attempt is to call $A$ such an event. Note

$$ P(A) = 1 - P(\text{no six}) = 1 - \left(\frac 5 {12} \right)^{12}$$

IS this correct? The problem confuses because I dont really understand whether they mean to throw the dice one by one or all at  the same time.

Comment: I think you misread the question. You're throwing an individual die $12$ times. The probability of getting a six on an individual toss is $\frac{1}{6}$ and the probability of not getting a six on an individual toss is $\frac{5}{6}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not accounted for the probability of getting exactly one six.

Letting $X$ denote the number of sixes we observed,

$$P(X\geq 2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)$$

The probability that an individual die is not a six is $\frac{5}{6}$ so

$$P(X=0)=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12}$$

Can you go from here to solve for $P(X=1)$ noting that exactly one success can occur in $12$ places?

Comment: Why do we need exactly one six? I am very confused

Comment: We wish to find the probability of $2$ or more successes so we must subtract off the probability of getting exactly $0$ successes and exactly $1$ success.